# How to move FloatingActionButton to specific fragment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How do I move `FloatingActionButton` only to specific fragment layout that I want? For example, only show to fragment B, while fragment A eliminated.

My code

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.bertho.tdashboard.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.bertho.tdashboard.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my **fragment_channel**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I want to move `FloatingActionButton` from **app_bar_main** to **fragment_channel** layout.

When I try, I get a look messy when moving `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` and `FloatingActionButton` inside **fragment_channel**.

How is the correct way to put Floating Action Button only on the layout of a particular fragment (in this case `fragment_channel`) ?

Comment: Case closed by me....

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in my case. Hope it helps you.

**- app_bar_main.xml**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="com.bertho.tdashboard.MainActivity"
  >

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**- content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context="com.bertho.tdashboard.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And now in you **fragment_channel.xml** put **FrameLayout** as parent and before close it, put your FAB.

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

             <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
             android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />

             </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

             <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
             android:id="@+id/fab"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
             android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_new_user" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

---

To finish, remove the **FAB** code in **MainActivity** and implement it in your **ChannelFragment.java**.

Hope Helpful